# Python Telegram API: What Correct way to use HTML <a> with accent?

Tags: python, html, api, url, telegram

Part of the href is not a link because of the accent (õ), How I can fix it?

```
        _bot_token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        _bot_chatID = "@xxxxxxxxxx"
        linkhtml = '<a href="' + 'http://filetitle-thisPartIsNotLinkõthisPartIsLink.pdf' + '">' + 'test' + '</a>'
        print(linkhtml)
        bot_message =  linkhtml
        send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + _bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + _bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=HTML&disable_web_page_preview=True&text=' + bot_message    
        response = requests.get(send_text)
```

[image]

Comment: url encode the link?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen quote or quote_plus function to encode didn't work, it keeps the same. Othe solution?

Comment: Also if you only encode the problematic character? Ie `http://filetitle-thisPartIsNotLink%C3%B5thisPartIsLink.pdf`

Comment: @RJAdriaansen same situation if I encode manually with %C3%B5...
link only works if I remove problematic character totally

Answer (score 1):

You can use `quote or quote_plus` function from `urllib.parse` module to slove this problem.

> The URL quoting functions focus on taking program data and making it safe for use as URL components by quoting special characters and appropriately encoding non-ASCII text. They also support reversing these operations to recreate the original data from the contents of a URL component if that task isn’t already covered by the URL parsing functions above.

[Python Documentations - URL Quoting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-quoting)

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

url = 'http://filetitle-thisPartIsNotLinkõthisPartIsLink.pdf'
linkhtml = '<a href="' + quote_plus(url) + '">' + 'test' + '</a>'
print(linkhtml)
```

Comment: I already tried and it didn't work :/  first part of the text is not a link